# How to make an API call with key secret in flutter using getconnect?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-getx

My app need to communicate with the server using **REST API**, my **API contains key and secret**. I need to establish the connection with server and fetch the data from server using **GetX library** with the help of **GetConnect**.

Here is the piece of code I'm using to communicate with the server, to fetch the data from server based on user-id but I'm not able to achieve it.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_connect.dart';

class ApiService extends GetConnect {

  final _baseUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/';           // Dummy End Point
  final _headersMap = {'SANBOX-API': 'VN0VQ2DW651L91Y25TVO'};  // Dummy REST API key and secret

  // Fetch User Friends
  Future<UserFriends?> fetchUserFriends({required String userId}) async {
    String apiUrl = '${_baseUrl}user_firends?user_id=${userId}';
    final response = await get(apiUrl, headers: _headersMap);
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      return userFriendsFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
   }
  }
```

When ever I **execute** this snippet code, I'm getting **null**

Guide me what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: isn't response ok? ` return userFriendsFromJson(response.body);` response.body may string . so you need to  json.decode(response.body). where you get null this code.stacktrace provide

Comment: The response form the server is json format only, I tired json.decode(response.body) but still I'm not able to fetch the data.

Comment: what you get in `response.body` could you print

Comment: I'm getting **null** when I print response.body

Comment: did you check the api in postman .did you get?

Comment: yes, I'm getting data in postman.